# Intermittent API/SSL Issue

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I've been working with an API for some time now with which calls work for the majority of the time however occasionally (1 to 2 times a day for around an hour, although it's completely unpredictable when and how long for!) I get the following error message:

"An error has occurred: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'api.xxxxx.com'"

I've been monitoring the api both with scheduled calls from my server and externally using runscope and also manually with Postman. When my server calls have the issue runscope and Postman do not suggesting it's a problem on my side.

FYI I'm querying the api from a linux server using PHP to run basic authentication with both file_get_contents and Curl - both approaches display the same issue.

Having worked with the super helpful api owner dev team it appears that, upon using the openssl command:

echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername api.XXXXX.com -connect api.XXXXX.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text

my server is somehow pointing the api's domain to my own, i.e. this command outputs my own ssl certificate and not that of the api.

Does anyone know how to fix this and/or stop this happening again?

Comment: The most obvious cause is that the service is running on multiple servers but with different configs/certificates. Do you know if the API runs on a single server or multiples? Why not set up a job to poll the api certificate periodically and see if its changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a subject alternative name is a way of using one certificate for multiple virtual hosts - you are essentially getting a name mismatch error when connecting to the server, at some point you are connecting to a secure URL that the certificate knows nothing about, paste all of your API endpoint urls into this checker https://www.digicert.com/help/

if you have an api myapi.example.com and a signed certificate you can't make secure calls to myotherapi.example.com unless you have stated myotherapi.example.com as a subject alternative name or you have a wildcard certificate.

the fact that it only does this once a day could be down to load balancing, if you have 2 or more servers in a load balanced pool make sure that the SSL off loading is applied to both servers - otherwise the load balancer may direct you occasionally to a host with a self signed certificate (if you have encrypted the channel between your load balancer and your hosts) - if the servers **are** load balanced **and** SSL is off loaded for both servers correctly - then make sure there apache ServerName is exactly the same i.e. not api1.example.com and api2.example.com

lastly make sure you only have one DNS entry pointing to the load balancers virtual IP

Comment: Thanks for the input rob however I have a wildcard certificate and am not using a load balancer, this is a simple 1 dedicated server setup. As you can see I've now updated the question to hone in more specifically on the issue.

Comment: the only way this could be happening is is api.XXXXXX.com is being redirected - is there any difference between "ping api.XXXXX.com" and "nslookup api.XXXXX.com"

Comment: Nope, no difference, both output the same ip

Comment: then it must be curl - can you try editing some of the curl options particularly test changing follow location to false if it is true CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false

Comment: No, i don't think it's CURL I've tried using both file_get_contents and CURL and both fail (both also tried separately.) Besides, as described with the question update, isn't this an OpenSSL issue? What I'm trying to find out is why my server is intermittently pointing the api's domain to my own?

Comment: it's an SSL issue but it's linked to networking as it's a redirect - do you get a warning when you 'wget https://api.XXXX.com' and if you do what is the output of 'wget --no-check-certificate https://api.XXXX.com'

Comment: the (https) was stripped in my comments

Comment: I get the following:Resolving api.XXXX.com... 175.41.255.20, 54.248.74.224, 46.51.253.206, ...
Connecting to api.XXXX.com|175.41.255.20|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://api.XXXX.com/login [following]
--2016-04-19 12:57:59--  http://api.XXXX.com/login
Connecting to api.XXXX.com|175.41.255.20|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301

Comment: Moved Permanently
Location: https://api.XXXX.com/login [following]
--2016-04-19 12:57:59--  https://api.XXXX.com/login
Connecting to api.XXXX.com|175.41.255.20|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html.3'

Comment: if you look in the index.html - is it from your server or the api server?

Comment: It looks to be from my server

Comment: that's because curl will not following redirects unless you tell it to, and the api operators are redirecting from an aws-ec2 instance name, try 'curl -L api.XXXXX.com' - there will still be a certificate error

Comment: But why would this be so intermittent, i.e. work sometimes and not others? Also why would the file_get_contents also fail when used on it's own?

Comment: two reasons, the site is published 3 times, put the 3 ip address above from comment into a browser, this alone is crazy and file_get_content is actually working - it's getting the 301 redirect

Comment: But why would the calls work sometimes (the majority of the time) and not others? Also, how does this explain the openssl pointing to my domain?

Comment: it's doning dns 'round robin' - your server looks up api.XXXX.com and it get's an IP address, that IP address is cached to 60 seconds, then you run another command, it does DNS and gets a different IP address and when it connects it's a 301 redirect, your probably getting your ssl cert from a proxy server?

Comment: there should not be a 301 in front of an API - they need to fix it.

Comment: Oh dear, this sounds like a complete mess, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: since in AWS, it should be load balanced with a single IP, the SSL cert should be on the load balancer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html#create-https-lb-console

Comment: So there is nothing I can do from my side? Apparently I'm the only one with this issue using the api?

Comment: the in that case you must have 3 different DNS entries for api.xxxxx.com, delete the entry with the 301 redirect. whichever one is hosting this page.  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://api.xxxxxx.com/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>

Comment: ok, sorry, hopefully last question, where do i delete these records, as far as i know I've never set any up for the api on my server?

Comment: actually they all have the 301, you should be fine so long as to use curl -L

Comment: Thanks for the extensive help here Rob, in the end I've disabled my DNS cache and enabled Curl to follow redirects, this seems to have done the trick so far - 24 hours without a failure. Thanks again for the input, I've learn't a lot!!